# onClick function to remove and add class not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sidebar menu with anchor link. The idea is simple: Once someone clicks on a menu item, that specific item gets the "active" class and the previous "active" menu item gets that class removed.

Somehow the code doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

This is the page:
https://www.otto-keller.de/wissenswertes/

```js
function setActive(element){
    var menuitems = document.querySelectorAll(".leftmenu_item.active");
        [].forEach.call(menuitems, function(el) {
                  el.classList.remove("active");
        });
    element.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="leftmenu_item active" onclick="setActive(this)">
        <a href="#daunenfedern">Daunen &amp; Federn</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leftmenu_item " onclick="setActive(this)">
        <a href="#inlett">Inlett</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leftmenu_item " onclick="setActive(this)">
        <a href="#allergiker">Allergiker</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leftmenu_item " onclick="setActive(this)">
        <a href="#waschmittel">Waschmittel</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
function setActive(element){
   var menuitems = document.querySelectorAll(".leftmenu_item.active");
   [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("active");
   });
   element.classList.add("active");
}
```

I tried to look first for the element that has the active class already to remove it. Then add the "active" class to the element which was clicked on with onclick().

Somehow it doesn't work on the live page, but does work in the editor.

Comment: please provide [mcve] in post

Comment: What is `elems`?

Comment: Also note that in modern browsers you can use `.forEach()` directly on a NodeList value.

Comment: What is this `[].forEach`? Why are you running a `forEach` on a hard coded empty `Array` `[]`?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon it's using the empty array as a quick way to access `Array.prototype.forEach()`, which is then invoked via `.call()`.

Comment: @Pointy That leads use to `elems` being `undefined`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon yes, and that's why I think this question should be closed as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```js
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("active");
});
```

To this

```js
menuitems.forEach((element, index, entireList) => {
    element.classList.remove("active");
});
```

Iterate over the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by `document.querySelectorAll()` instead of the `[]` like you did earlier. [See the correct signature for the `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by looping your elements, adding them a `click` event listener which calls `setActive`, passing the element to be set to active. Inside `setActive`, we check whether the current element is already active in which case we do nothing. Otherwise, we find the previously active element and, if it exists, then we remove the active class from it and then we proceed adding the active class to the element that was clicked.

```js
function setActive(currentElem){
    if (!currentElem.classList.contains("active")) {
        let previousActive = document.querySelector(".leftmenu_item.active");
        if (previousActive) previousActive.classList.remove("active");
        currentElem.classList.add("active");
    }
}


for (let currentElem of document.querySelectorAll(".leftmenu_item")) {
    currentElem.addEventListener("click", function() {
        setActive(this);
    });
}
```

```css
.leftmenu_item.active {
    background-color: green;
}

.leftmenu_item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftmenu_item active"></div>
<div class="leftmenu_item"></div>
<div class="leftmenu_item"></div>
<div class="leftmenu_item"></div>
<div class="leftmenu_item"></div>
<div class="leftmenu_item"></div>
<div class="leftmenu_item"></div>
```

Comment: It is linear, as you have a single select inside `setActive`. The other loop is just adding the event, which happens once, before the click actually happens. But I would not really worry about the number of menu items on a UI.

Comment: @LajosArpad and what is the time complexity of a call to `.querySelector()`? This is needlessly complicated.

Comment: @Pointy it's a single search. One can save the previously active element, but that's adding further concepts to this answer and making it more difficult to understand for a beginner. Besides that, if I create a global to store the previously active element, then I would be criticized for that. But, if I implement the complete mechanism to manage the previously active menu, then it would be further complication for beginner. And then we would need to implement the initial collection and determination whether an active element is present and if so which one.

Comment: @Pointy therefore, when writing this answer, my main aim was to write code that's easier to understand for a beginner. Besides that, the accepted answer relies on `var menuitems = document.querySelectorAll(".leftmenu_item.active");`, a search that was not criticized and its author criticized my answer for having a similar search. In my opinion optimizing this algorithm is a different topic.